# OPAM "Illegal Instruction: 4" for Infer Static Analyzer

Tags: terminal, homebrew, static-analysis, opam

Currently I am trying to run opam commands but they return illegal instruction 4. I have the latest version of homebrew installed, OSX El Capitan 10.11.1 on a Mid 2010 Mac Book Pro. I have opam installed and linked but every time I try "opam init -y --comp=4.01.0", "opam init", "opam update", "opam --help" ect... I get returned "Illegal Instruction: 4". I have tried reinstalling homebrew and opam.

The point of this is that I am trying to run a static analysis on objective c code. I am doing this prerequisite for the The built in analyzer is not picking up on some things that I believe it should. Also if you have any other suggestions for a static analyzer for objective c it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try `brew reinstall --build-from-source opam`